# Como achar o maior elemento de um vetor de forma recursiva?

Tags: java

Só consegui fazer da forma iterativa, mas recursiva não faço nem ideia de como começar.

Comment: Demonstre que teve esforço tentando fazer algo e edite a pergunta, a sua outra ja foi fechada sem você adicionar isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dê uma olhada nesses links: [recursividade em java](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3316/recursividade-em-java.aspx), [pergunta em fórum-recursividade java](http://www.guj.com.br/t/recursividade/83357/2).

Não vou fazer o código todo para você pois isso tiraria parte do seu aprendizado, mas vou explicar como poderia funcionar.

Uma função recursiva é um função que chama à ela mesma.
Sendo assim, o que você poderia fazer é ter uma função / método que verifica se um determinado elemento do vetor é maior do que o **maior-encontrado** até agora.

Para isso, você pode ter uma variável global que armazena o maior elemento do vetor, e ir passando o índice atual que está "analisando" como parâmetro na função recursiva.

Um pseudo-código ficaria parecido com isso:

```
void achaMaior_recursivo(Vetor vet, Indice i){
    // se o índice atual tiver passado do último elemento do vetor, para a recursividade
    if (i >= vet.quantidadeDeElementos){
        return;
    } else {
        //se o elemento atual é o maior até agora, atualiza maiorEcontrado
        if (vet[i] > maiorEcontrado)
            maiorEncontrado = vet[i];

        //procura pelo maior elemento nos índices restantes
        achaMaior_recursivo(vet, i+1);
    }

}
```